# Tapastry error about not having a tml only for some requests

Tags: tapestry

```
Object onActivate(final String jsonRequest){
    return new StreamResponse() {

        private InputStream inputStream;

        public void prepareResponse(Response response) {
```

I'm using the above code to generate a XML as the response. When I test it in browser, it works fine. But when I send my request from Android application i get the following error on server side.

```
[ERROR] TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: Page catalog/Index did not generate any markup when rendered. This could be because its template file could not be located, or because a render phase method in the page prevented rendering.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Page catalog/Index did not generate any markup when rendered. This could be because its template file could not be located, or because a render phase method in the page prevented rendering.
```

Comment: How do you do your request in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find you have some errant URL in your template that is activating your page without a page activation context; your onActivate() event handler will not be invoked unless theres a value in the URL to satisfy the parameter, so it is skipped, and the default behavior ... rendering using a template, kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

When I send a GET request it worked. Previously I was sending a POST

Comment: I suspect something else is going on; Tapestry doesn't care about POST vs. GET, except that form submissions must be POST. Other than that, there is no difference.